# How to get more than the first 25 secrets from an Azure key vault via command line?

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I am using `az keyvault secret list` to get secrets from my Azure key vault. Its help says:

```
Arguments
    --maxresults                    : Maximum number of results to return in a page. If not
                                      specified, the service will return up to 25 results.
```

It is not possible to set `--maxresults` any higher than 25. The help says *"in a page"*, but I can find no explanation of how to get the *next page*.

Is it possible to list more than the top 25 secrets using this tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot get more than 25 Secret lists by using the `--maxresults` in the CLI command.

#### Please find the below workaround:

If we specify the `--maxresults` more than **25** the cli returns the below result.

```
Az keyvault secret list --vault-name <your keyvault name> --maxresults 30
```

[image]

If you want to **get all the Secrets** in a specific **key vault** you have to use the below command without using `--maxresults`.

```
Az keyvault secret list --vault-name <your keyvault name>
```

[image]

Or
If you want it to achieve programmatically need to write a script with the **REST API** or some language library directly. Refer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/15382#issuecomment-757117986)

Answer (score 1):

To get all the secrets with name and value via azure cli in Mac, you can use the below script:
`sh keyvault-list.sh keyvaultname`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

keyvaultEntries=($(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $1 --query "[*].{name:name}" -o tsv))

for i in "${keyvaultEntries[@]}"
do
    # do whatever on "$i" here
    echo "$i"::"$(az keyvault secret show --name $i --vault-name $1 -o tsv --query value)"
done
```